# Problem with Merge Statement?

Tags: merge

I am trying to merge two lead records, please find below the code.

```
Lead leads = [SELECT Email,company,RFI_Record_Type__c FROM Lead WHERE email IN:emailSet and Email !=null and Id not IN:leadIds Order By CreatedDate DESC Limit 1];

List<Lead> newLeads = [SELECT Email,company,RFI_Record_Type__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN:leadIds and Email != null];

merge leads newleads;
```

`leads` is the master record and `newLeads` is the duplicate/new records. Both the SOQL queries return a row, which is good. When I debug, it shows both are merged and the merged record deleted which is good.

But When I again try to assert for the merged value by using a soql over leads as same as the first SOQL above, it returns the same old record but does not display any merged value.

If we merge a merged record with master record , then will all the fields on the merged record get copied into the master record ?

Any help would be nice to have.

Thank You

Comment: Can you show a little more of the code that you have above these couple of lines? How are `leadIds` and `emailSet` being populated.

Comment: We also need to see how you're doing the assert.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is simply that you need to query back for `Leads` to assert on.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer .

I can have something like.

leads.RFI_Record_Type__c=newLeads[0].RFI_Record_Type__c;

So, it updates the existing master record and deletes the merged record.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: This is just a work around though, I feel like if this question is going benefit future users, we should dig into why this was happening...

Comment: Sure. In reality if we  merge a merged record with master record , then will all the fields on the merged record get copied into the master record ?

Comment: yes, if values exist - you also don't have to worry about maintaining a field list or adding code which pulls valid fields from the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have lot of knowledge on the subject of merging, but seeing as no one has answered yet, I want to throw in my two cents.

On the [Merge Statement Documentation Page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_merge.htm) it states that you can either pass one or two sObjects to the merge statement as the second parameter. If you are passing two objects, you should do so in a list (as you are doing - which is good).

```
merge sObject sObject;
merge sObject sObject[];
```

What might be catching you here is that you can only merge one or two records into one record.  Since I can't see what your list look like, all I can do is suggest that you ensure that at most two records are being populated into your `newLeads` list.

A couple of questions that you should investigate:

> 1. Is `newLeads` always one or two records?
> 2. Do you have a few similar leads in `emailSet` that you may be incorrectly recognizing as the same lead?
> 3. Are you ensuring that your assert statement is querying fresh results for the modified lead?

Comment: Apex is case-insensitive - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_variables.htm

Comment: I thought that was only relevant for system variables.. my bad.

Comment: Allowing case-insensitive user-defined variables seems like an excellent way to allow for sloppy/messy code.  Regardless of whether or not it is allowed, I feel that programmers should attempt to be consistent with variable names.  Maybe that's just my OCD.

Comment: The record is getting merged, which i see in the debug log but the values are not getting updated on the master record..any pointers for this..

Comment: I agree that consistent naming is important.

Comment: I have the name consistent in my code , i misspelled in the snippet above.